# Giving a .java Servlet File as welcome file in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there ant way that I can give the .java(Basically a servlet file ) which is under the "src" folder as the welcome file in the web.xml file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and remove both the `<welcome-file-list>` element and `index.html`.

Works fine.

Comment: Thank you all! I will try the solutions in just a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml you can specify the welcome file to map to a servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>foo.bar.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.foo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/welcome.foo</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I would assume that this also works on App Engine.

Of course, this would invoke the compiled servlet, not the source code in the "src" folder (which is most likely not even deployed to the server).

Comment: What does the below error mean.HTTP ERROR 403
Problem accessing /. Reason: 

    FORBIDDEN


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Powered by Jetty://